# change the width of the popover in swift

Tags: swift, popover

I want to change the width of the popover and keep the height is same

for example, if you open popover on iPad, the height is something like 70%-80% of the screen. I want to keep it same, but need to increase the width

I can use this block of clode, but here I have to enter the height as well, which is I don't want.

```
let vc = segue.destinationViewController
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `height` adjust to the size of the screen

```
var heightVariable = (self.view.frame.size.height * 70) / 100
```

Now, with `heightVariable` , height gonna always be %70 of the screen height.So you dont need to give constant to height

```
let vc = segue.destinationViewController
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: heightVariable) // change width
```

By the way ,You can detect device and change view's properties with using `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` like :

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad{
    // change width

 }else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone{
// change width
 }
```